# Get button text via python list recursively

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I have a DropDown with many buttons and a list with many strings, so each text from the buttons should be the strings from the list (button1 have the first string from list, button2 the seconds string, and so on. The problem is that all my buttons texts have only the last string from the list.

I basically tried to do a simple loop, where I loop over the list and set the result in the StringProperty, and put the StringProperty on the "text" from the button in kv file.

.py:

```
# Here is the list
clientes = ['Sercom', 'Lideranca', 'Winover']



class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    button_text = StringProperty('Clients')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyScreenManager, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.dropdown = CustomDropDown1(self)

    def open_drop_down(self, widget):
        self.dropdown.open(widget)

class MyScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)



class CustomDropDown1(DropDown):
    client_text = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, screen_manager, **kwargs):
        super(CustomDropDown1, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.sm = screen_manager
        self.is2Displayed = False

        # Here is my loop
        for message in clientes: 
            self.client_text = message



class GuiApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyScreenManager()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    GuiApp().run()
```

.kv:

```
<MyScreenManager>:
    MyScreen:
        FloatLayout:
            Button:
                text: root.button_text
                size: (200, 50)
                size_hint:(None,None)
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'top': 1.0}
                on_release: root.open_drop_down(self)

<CustomDropDown1>:
    padding: [0,0,0,0]
    Button:
        text: root.client_text
        size:(200,50)
        size_hint:(None,None)
        text_size: self.size
        valign: 'center'
        padding: (10,0)
        on_release: root.select(self.text)
    Button:
        text: root.client_text
        size:(200,50)
        size_hint:(None,None)
        text_size: self.size
        valign: 'center'
        padding: (10,0)
        on_release: root.select(self.text)
```

In my case, the text from the first button should be "Sercom", second button should be "Lideranca", and third button "Winover".

but the text from all the buttons are "Winover"

Comment: All your buttons use `root.client_text` for their text. That is just one `StringProperty`, so all those buttons will end up with whatever string is finally in that `StringProperty`. Is your `clientes` list going to be changing?

Comment: @JohnAnderson I will be updating the list yes, it will be added more names and buttons.

Comment: You will be adding names and buttons, but will the names for any button change? Or will the name assigned to a specific button remain the same while `GuiApp` is running.

Comment: @JohnAnderson The previous buttons will never change, but the next added button should have a different text from the other buttons. (where it comes from the list).

Answer (score 0):

Since your button text is not going to change, you don't need the `client_text` `StringProperty`. The `StringProperty` is excellent if you need to change the text of a `Button` or `Label`, but not necessary here.

There are several ways to accomplish what you want. Here is my first thought using the `clientes` list directly. I have moved the `clientes` list inside the `CustomDropDown1` class, since that is where it is used.

```
class CustomDropDown1(DropDown):
    clientes = ['Sercom', 'Lideranca', 'Winover']

    def __init__(self, screen_manager, **kwargs):
        super(CustomDropDown1, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.sm = screen_manager
        self.is2Displayed = False

        for button_num in range(2):
            id = 'button' + str(button_num)
            self.ids[id].text = self.clientes[button_num]
```

I also added ids to your buttons, and removed the `text:` properties in the `kv` file:

```
<CustomDropDown1>:
    padding: [0,0,0,0]
    Button:
        id: button0
        size:(200,50)
        size_hint:(None,None)
        text_size: self.size
        valign: 'center'
        padding: (10,0)
        on_release: root.select(self.text)
    Button:
        id: button1
        size:(200,50)
        size_hint:(None,None)
        text_size: self.size
        valign: 'center'
        padding: (10,0)
        on_release: root.select(self.text)
```

So each button has an `id` of the form 'button#' where '#' is the button number, then the loop in the `__init__()` method of `CustomDropDown1` builds the button id based on the number and sets the text by using the number as an index into the `clientes` list.

Another approach is to eliminate the loop entirely and just set the button text as

```
text: root.clientes[0]
```

for the first button, and

```
text: root.clientes[1]
```

for the next, and so on (with the `clientes` list in the `CustomDropDown1` class).